# Why does XElement not behave like a reference type?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I noticed that `XElement` is a class, so I tried something like:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Root")
    );
var root = doc.Root;
var com = new XElement("Component", new XAttribute("name", "arm"));
root.Add(com);
root.Add(com);
root.Add(com);
com.Add(new XAttribute("type", 1));

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

but the output is:

```
<Root>
  <Component name="arm" type="1" />
  <Component name="arm" />
  <Component name="arm" />
</Root>
```

I also tried `SetAttributeValue()`, and got the same result.

Why is the type attribute only attached to the first component?

Comment: Because it's [made that way](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/valid-content-xelement-xdocument-objects#valid-types-for-the-xelement-constructor). "When adding `XNode` or `XAttribute` objects, if the new content has no parent, then the objects are simply attached to the XML tree. If the new content already is parented and is part of another XML tree, then the new content is cloned, and the newly cloned content is attached to the XML tree." If you think about it, trying to maintain reference semantics would lead to very unintuitive results when asking about document order.

Comment: Why not just put `com.Add(new XAttribute("type", 1));` before `root.Add(com);`, not after?

Comment: If you prefer to look into [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,2419), then you will see it would call a `CloneNode()` method for following up calls (since the parent for `com` will be set). By modifying `com` instance you will only change first node, which was not cloned.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unless there's a dup-target (I couldn't find one), you might want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've given a second answer below - better because it gives a concrete design reason why - but left this one because it evidences that internal copy has taken place.

---

Being a class does not give a clue as to how that class behaves or should be treated.

Using the debugger

[image: Hashcodes per node]

Each Node has a different hash and must therefore be assumed to be a different object (so presumably there is copying going on during `Add()`).

If you can change the order of your operations, this fixes the problem

```
static void X()
{
  var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Root")
  );
  var root = doc.Root;
  var com = new XElement("Component", new XAttribute("name", "arm"));
  com.Add(new XAttribute("type", 1));
  root.Add(com);
  root.Add(com);
  root.Add(com);

  Console.WriteLine(doc);
}
```

giving

```
<Root>
  <Component name="arm" type="1" />
  <Component name="arm" type="1" />
  <Component name="arm" type="1" />
</Root>
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem, it hides it. The presence of the attributes on all nodes may make you think they are indeed the same instance, which they are not. They are three copies just like before.

Comment: @GSerg: I agree it is not intuitive but that does not make it wrong.  Clearly this is by-design behavior.  I am proposing the use of the class should change to fix the behavior, are you suggesting that the class should change to accommodate this type of use?

Answer (score 1):

My original answer stands (essentially "by design") and here is a reason why...

From [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=net-5.0) (and following the relevant links) you will find that

- `XElement` inherits `XContainer` inherits `XNode`
- `XContainer` has method `Add()` and properties `FirstNode` and `LastNode`
- `XNode` has properties `NextNode` and `PreviousNode`

If `Add()` blindly added references to the same object without creating copies where necessary to avoid multiple-referencing, how could circular references be avoided?  In your example above, `FirstNode` and `FirstNode.NextNode` would reference the same object.